# How can I customize windows authentication pop up in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

As before I post question to stack here :

[How Can I pass EffectiveUserName to SSAS through Excel Service using FBA(Forms based authentication) in SharePoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829021/how-can-i-pass-effectiveusername-to-ssas-through-excel-service-using-fbaforms-b)

Finally I decided to use claim based windows authentication, because this mode send EffectiveUserName to ssas from excel service.

Now we need to create a custom claim based windows authenticated login page in SharePoint 2013 without another authentication method.
picture below shows popup window:

[image]

I exactly want to create a custom aspx page that works like this popup page. when users want to login , this aspx shows instead of pop up windows security.

There are a little references to do this like

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chunliu/2010/09/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication/

but it is not work and is not complete and does not help. users want to login to system using only and only this authentication method. how to customize it?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: We first use FBA to login users. everything was good until our project employer wants to show only subset of data from SSAS cube for each user based on their role which has already been defined in SSAS side.

We test alot of things, like sss(Secure store box) but none of them pass EffectiveUserName to SSAS. because of this, roles dont apply on cube and an error raised in excel service in sharepoint 2013. 
but when i use Windows Auth, Effective user name passed to SSAS.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after plowing Internet a lot i find this. here you are : [VsFile](https://dpcrew.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/signinwithwindowsclaims.zip)

Comment: THANK YOU for posting this. was losing my mind here:) .  I am still getting one error on      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => federationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(token, SPSessionTokenWriteType.WritePersistentCookie));    object reference not set to an instance of an object. My securitytoken does not have any security keys. could that be the reason?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell why you are getting NullReferenceException without having full stack trace of the exception in hand. But as a wild guess I can say it maybe is the federationAuthenticationModule that is null.
But I guess you should open another question for the issue. I will be happy to help if you post the address to that question here.